Combine/transition animations
My character is animated to walk to the end of the path at frame 100. How can I get him to do the remaining "Attack emote," at the end of the path?
File: https://we.tl/t-rY0zhkre4T
Thanks

Hello, you need to move the strip at frame 100 and also in the N panel choose Extrapolation > Nothing. That said this action contains a walk so it doesn't make a lot of sense as it will continue to walk at the end of the curve

Hi Moonboots, thanks for your response. If my action contains a walk cycle, how do I get my character to do his combo at the end of the path?

I'm not sure to understand, maybe edit this action in the Dope Sheet in order to remove the beginning and keep only the keyframes you want?
